# How do I solve multiple joins producing duplicate application_id in sql query result

Tags: sql

I have this query below and when I include the last join, I keep getting duplicate applicationid is the query result

```
select distinct 
    a.id,
    a.application_id,
    a.ref_num_sequence,
    a.payment_date, 
    a.payment_status,
    po.name,
    pi.booklet_fee as application_amount,
ph.fee_amount as application_tr_charge,
pi.address_verification_fee,
pi.address_verification_service_charge,
ph.payment_gateway
from applicant a
join processing_info pi on pi.applicant_id = a.id
join payment_header ph  on ph.applicant_id = pi.applicant_id
join passport_office po on po.id = pi.processing_office
where a.payment_status = '200' and 
a.payment_date between '2022-03-04 00:00:00' and '2022-03-08 23:59:59' and 
po.name IN('Enugu','Awka','Owerri','Abakaliki','Umuahia')
order by a.payment_date desc
```

Comment: The value for `po.id` does exists multiple times in `pi.processing_office`  (`pi.processing_office` is not unique)

Comment: Luuk is correct.  To resolve you will need to change the query to not join to passport_office unless you can make the join unique with some other column.  How you do this and get po.name depends on the database you are using, Sql Server you could use outer apply but that doesn't exist in all databases.  An answer depends on what variety of sql you are using.